# Dota 2 lag 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04, steam

When I launch Dota 2 I have a lot of lag. In the main menu, where there is fog everywhere, yellow pixels appear, when I go to the trial map or the lobby everything is fine, but when I move the camera I get 8 fps. Also in the game, icons of items and various abilities without textures.

I am a new ubuntu user.

My PC:

> 16 GB Memory 
> Intel® Core™ i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz × 6 
> GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER MINI ITX OC [GV-N166SIXOC-6GD]

[image]